# Isotope filtering with value comparison

Tags: filtering, jquery-isotope

I have a question about isotope filtering.
I want to filter games that have 2 values, min players value and max players value, ie the number of people that can play together with this game.

```
<div class="column item xxx" data-playermin="4" data-playermax="6" </div>
```

I use data attributes, but don't know if it's ok to do this ?

Then, i want to have a text field where we can enter a value, ie the number of players they are. Then, the items-games displayed should have this entered value  between min and max.

Do you think it is possible ?

Thanks for your help !